# Why is that when I am scrolling up or down the list it activates a Switch listener in my custom cursor adapter?

Tags: android

I can see through the toasts that I have implemented and debugging that when I scroll up or down on my list the onCheckedChanged method is called from my listener. I am recycling the views (view holder pattern) and would imagine that the recycling of views is causing the problem but not sure what to do. Here is the code for the custom cursor adapter -

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;
private int res;
private String mgName;
private String mMfg;
private String mRarity;
private String mLoosePrice;
private String mgYear;
private String mYear_Mfg;
private int mOwned;
private boolean isOwned;
private Switch mySwitch;
private String mID;
private String mIDfinal;
private View v;
private int position = 1;


public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    v = cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.game);
    holder.textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_Title);
    holder.textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_mfg);
    holder.textView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rarity_value);
    holder.textView4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.loose_cart_value);
    holder.switch1 = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.owned_switch);
    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

//Determines row colors
    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bbbbbb"));
        position++;
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7b7b7b"));
        position++;
    }
    if (position > 10) {
        position = 1;
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String mboxArt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    mboxArt = "a" + mboxArt;
    res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mboxArt, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    mgName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gName"));
    mMfg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mfg"));
    mgYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gYear"));
    mYear_Mfg = mMfg + "," + mgYear;
    mRarity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("rarity"));
    mOwned = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("cart"));
    mLoosePrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lPrice"));
//        mID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("My_Collection_T._id"));
//        mIDfinal = "'" + mID + "'";

    if (mOwned == 1) {
        isOwned = true;
    } else {
        isOwned = false;
    }
    view.setTag(holder);


    holder.imageView.setImageResource(res);

    holder.textView1.setText(mgName);

    holder.textView2.setText(mYear_Mfg);

    holder.textView3.setText(mRarity);

    holder.textView4.setText(mLoosePrice);

    holder.switch1.setChecked(isOwned);

//Listener for owned switch
mySwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.owned_switch);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        ContentValues mNewValues = new ContentValues();
        TextView gameN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.game_Title);
        CharSequence text = gameN.getText();
        text = "'" + text + "'";
        String gameName = text.toString();
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
            mNewValues.put("cart", 1);
            mNewValues.put("numCart", 1);
            gameName = "gName = " + gameName;
            mContext.getContentResolver().update(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues, gameName, null);

            ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = resolver.query(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            //For debugging -
            if (c != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                dumpCursor(c, sb);
                String result = sb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
                c.close();
            }
            /////////////////////////
            mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null);
        } else {
            mNewValues.put("cart", 0);
            mNewValues.put("numCart", 0);
            gameName = "gName = " + gameName;
            mContext.getContentResolver().update(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues, gameName, null);

            ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = resolver.query(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            //For debugging
            if (c != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                dumpCursor(c, sb);
                String result = sb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
                c.close();
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////
            mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(GamesContract.My_Collection_T.CONTENT_URI, null);
        }
    }
});

}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;
    TextView textView4;
    Switch switch1;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, calling `setChecked(boolean)` triggers the listener, even if you do it programmatically. That is, there's no way to know whether a user clicked it or if you changed the state programmatically.

Since the Views are recycled, the first time you create the view, `owned_switch` has no listener attached. You then set the state:

```
holder.switch1.setChecked(isOwned);
```

and then attach a listener:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...);
```

And everything works as expected. However, after the view is recycled, it still has the listener attached (the same `View` is returned as `convertView` in `getView()`), so the call to:

```
holder.switch1.setChecked(isOwned);
```

will trigger the original listener that you've set on the view previously. One simple workaround would be to null out the listener before adjusting the checked state and resetting the listener:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder.switch1.setChecked(isOwned);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...);
```

Also, not sure why you're making a new variable for `mySwitch`, as it's the same view as `holder.switch1`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that setChecked was triggering my listener. Part of my issue to was that my cursor was not properly being notified of data update. I fixed it by putting setNotifiaction in my query method and everything is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated, since you are recycling the same components, as you scroll up or down, depending upon the item being displayed, the switch button settings (ON/OFF) change. So the switch button which might be set to true in one place for that item will now be showing false for another item in another place (you get the idea) as there is a listener that was attached to this switch. That's an expected outcome of recycling while using the ViewHolder pattern.

One thing you could do is to have a method that resets the onCheckedChanged() listener.